# How to prevent spam URLs in a PHP contact form

Tags: php, forms

I have created a form where a user can add a review. Perhaps this is very obvious but how can I avoid a user inserting a url in the text area. Is there a way to check this? 
I have put in a captcha to check for humans.

```
<form action="" method="POST" name="form">
  some other input fields

             <span id="sprytextarea1">
             <textarea name="Comments" cols="50" rows="3" ></textarea>
             <span class="textareaRequiredMsg">A value is required.</span></span></p>

  <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image" /><input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6" />

<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>

  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit your form ">
           <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form">
           </form>
```

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: That's what the CAPTCHA is for - to *minimize* bots/spam (although it's easily defeated with wage differentials). Now, one could *remove* all URLs or URL-like text, but that would defeat non-spam links and wouldn't prevent clever representations. Alternatively, require authentication and trust that someone who takes time to register won't spam.

Comment: how about validating the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP you can try two things using preg_match() and strip_tags() or a combination of them both. below will clean the textarea, escape it as well for database.

Once the form is submitted try this.

```
$post = array();

foreach($_POST as $k => $v){

// strip all HTML and escape values for database

$post[$k] = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($v));
}

// check of we have URL in text area

if(preg_match('/www\.|http:|https:/'i,$post['Comments']){

// prevent form from saving code goes here
echo 'error please remove URLs';

}else{
// let form be saved
}
```

Comment: Use prepared statements to put unsafe contents in DB. PDO and MySQLi do provide methods for them. Even, mysql_* functions are deprecated.

Comment: Not entirely sure how a Captcha is mean't to prevent a user directly inserting a URL into the form, that's not what they do.

The OP asked if there was a way to check the form for and prevent a user inserting a URL. Above code should do this. The Captcha would seem to fulfill one purpose and that's to prevent spam reviews from bots or non-humans.

Comment: I didn't talked about captcha.

Comment: The regex in this answer will, in most cases, suffice for checking if there is a URL in the subject. The database stuff in this answer should be avoided like the plague, however (deprecated, not safe, etc).

Comment: Thanks Leon your answer was the right one. I just had to change a few bits this is how it ended up:                                                 if (preg_match( '/www\.|http:|https:\/\/[a-z0-9_]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z_0-9]+)*\.[_a-z]{2,5}'.'((:[0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$/i', $_POST['Comments'])){

Comment: The use of `mysql_real_escape_string()` should not be used by researchers.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the if condition,before insert db.

```
if(preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp|http):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$_POST['comment'])){

echo 'error please remove URLs';

}else
{....
```

Comment: This does not prevent all URLs, for example, it does not prevent `aahttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254482/how-to-prevent-spam-urls-in-a-php-contact-form`

Answer (score 0):

Simply, there is no any automatic way to check a URL in input text. You just have to use a human check for the user input.

For example: suppose that you tried to apply regex check for a URL and I want to trick it, I may able to write infinite string that shown as a URL:

- http: example .com
- h ttp:// ecxampleDOTcom
- ht-tp: / / ecample. Com
- etc

So any commenting system to achieve the ultimate spam protection, it applies moderator review in which a human being check the content.